# Check integrity of inserted data - sqlite3

Tags: mysql, sql, c, csv, sqlite

I have a "large" file in csv format (159 G) that I have inserted into a database table using Sqlite3 and C. Now, the actual csv file has 1,232,799,308 rows (1 billion+). However only (123,254,689) have been inserted. I have three questions:

1) How can I compare the inserted data against the actual once in the csv file? I mean I want to know whether the interested data is from one block (i.e. from row 1 till row 100,000,000) or it is random?

2) Is there a way to know whether the inserted rows represent the whole population, in terms of the sampling rate (average, standard deviation, and margin of error)?

3) Is there a problem with the code that only 10% of the rows got inserted!?

Thanks in advance for the help guys :)

The code is in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

#define INPUTDATA "/nobackup/DSS/clusterdata-2011-1/working_data/task_usage.csv"
#define DATABASE "/nobackup/DSS/clusterdata-2011-1/working_data/google.db"
#define TABLE "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS task_usageBS(startendtime TEXT, jobID TEXT, taskindex TEXT, machineID TEXT, CPUusage TEXT, MEMusage TEXT, assignedMEM TEXT, unmappedpagecacheMEMusage TEXT, pagecacheMEMusage TEXT, maxMEMusage TEXT, diskIOtimeMEAN TEXT, localdiskspaceusedMEAN TEXT, CPUusagemax TEXT, diskIOtimemax TEXT, cyclesperinstructionCPI TEXT, MEMaccessesperinstructionMAI TEXT, samplingrate TEXT, aggregationtype TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (startendtime, jobID, taskindex), FOREIGN KEY(jobID) REFERENCES job_events(jobID), FOREIGN KEY(taskindex) REFERENCES task_events(taskindex), FOREIGN KEY(machineID) REFERENCES machine_events(machineID))"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

sqlite3 * db;
sqlite3_stmt * stmt;
char * sErrMsg = 0;
const char * tail = 0;
int nRetCode;
int n = 0;

clock_t cStartClock;

FILE * pFile;
char sInputBuf [BUFFER_SIZE] = "\0";

char * sTS = 0;  /* startendtime */
char * sJI = 0;  /* jobID */
char * sTI = 0;  /* taskindex */
char * sMI = 0;  /* machineid */
char * sCUM = 0;  /* CPUusageMEAN */
char * sMU = 0;  /* MEMusage */
char * sAM = 0;  /* assignedMEM */
char * sUPCMU = 0;  /* unmappedpagecacheMEMusage */
char * sPCMU = 0;  /* pagecacheMEMusage */
char * sMMU = 0;  /* maxMEMusage */
char * sDIOTM = 0;  /* diskIOtimeMEAN */
char * sLDSUM = 0;  /* localdiskspaceusedMEAN */
char * sCUMAX = 0;  /* CPUusagemax */
char * sDIOTMAX = 0;  /* diskIOtimemax */
char * sCPI = 0;  /* cyclesperinstructionCPI */
char * sMAPI = 0;  /* MEMaccessesperinstructionMAI */
char * sSR = 0;  /* samplingrate */
char * sAT = 0;  /* aggregationtype */



char sSQL [BUFFER_SIZE] = "\0";

/*********************************************/
/* Open the Database and create the Schema */
sqlite3_open(DATABASE, &db);
sqlite3_exec(db, TABLE, NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);

/*********************************************/
/* Open input file and import into Database*/
cStartClock = clock();

    sprintf(sSQL, "INSERT INTO task_usageBS VALUES (@TS, @JI, @TI, @MI, @CUM, @MU, @AM, @UPCMU, @PCMU, @MMU, @DIOTM, @LDSUM, @CUMAX, @DIOTMAX, @CPI, @MAPI, @SR, @AT)");
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,  sSQL, BUFFER_SIZE, &stmt, &tail);
    //sqlite3_exec(db, sSQL, NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);

    sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);

    pFile = fopen (INPUTDATA,"r");
    while (!feof(pFile)) {

    fgets (sInputBuf, BUFFER_SIZE, pFile);

    sTS = strtok (sInputBuf, ",");
    sJI = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sTI = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sMI = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sCUM = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sMU = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sAM = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sUPCMU = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sPCMU = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sMMU = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sDIOTM = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sLDSUM = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sCUMAX = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sDIOTMAX = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sCPI = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sMAPI = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sSR = strtok (NULL, ",");
    sAT = strtok (NULL, ",");

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, sTS, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, sJI, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, sTI, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, sMI, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, sCUM, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, sMU, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, sAM, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, sUPCMU, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 9, sPCMU, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 10, sMMU, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 11, sDIOTM, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 12, sLDSUM, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 13, sCUMAX, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 14, sDIOTMAX, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 15, sCPI, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 16, sMAPI, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 17, sSR, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 18, sAT, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    sqlite3_step(stmt);

    sqlite3_clear_bindings(stmt);
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    n++;

    }
    fclose (pFile);

    sqlite3_exec(db, "END TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &sErrMsg);

    printf("Imported %d records in %4.2f seconds\n", n, (clock() - cStartClock) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use .import in sqlite3?

Comment: How can I do that? @AmokHuginnsson

Comment: You *must* check the return values of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step`; see [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Answer (score 0):

How to use .import in sqlite3 to import data.

sqlite3 can import data from CSV files assuming that few conditions are met, eg. both decimal point separator in numeric fields matches your locale and text encoding also matches your locale. Of course column count in your destination table should match number of fields in CVS file.

If those conditions are met you can simply invoke something along following lines:

```
sqlite3 db.sqlite
.import data.csv my_table
```

Where db.sqlite is your database file with all required schema in place,
data.csv is your CSV file with source data and my_table is your destination table.